# Binding an array of Instance Types as a parameter for Doctrine DQL

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

Is it possible to bind an array of types to a DQL query for use with `INSTANCE OF`?

For example, this is the Doctrine DQL for querying an entity by a single specified type.

```
<?php
$dql = <<<DQL
SELECT o FROM \MyProj\AbstractMyObject AS o 
WHERE o INSTANCE OF :type
DQL;
$q = $em->createQuery($dql);
$q->setParameter(
    'type',
    $em->getClassMetadata(AlphaObject::class);
);
$q->getResult();
```

What is the equivalent method to bind more than one type as a parameter to this query?

The is what I have tried. It doesn't error, but it also does not return any results.

```
<?php
$dql = <<<DQL
SELECT o FROM \MyProj\AbstractMyObject AS o 
WHERE o INSTANCE OF (:types)
DQL;
$q = $em->createQuery($dql);
$q->setParameter(
    'types',
    [
        $em->getClassMetadata(AlphaObject::class),
        $em->getClassMetadata(BetaObject::class)
    ]
);
$q->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
$dql = <<<DQL
SELECT o FROM \MyProj\AbstractMyObject AS o 
WHERE o INSTANCE OF :typeAlpha OR o  INSTANCE OF :typeBeta
DQL;
$q = $em->createQuery($dql);
$q->setParameters([
    'typeAlpha' => $em->getClassMetadata(AlphaObject::class),
     'typeAlpha' => $em->getClassMetadata(BetaObject::class)
    ]
);
$q->getResult();
```

Comment: This will obviously work, but I was hoping for a way to pass an array instances rather than generating a DQL statement for a fixed set of parameters.

Comment: I think you can't do It what you want